Shopify integration with Auth0
I'm trying to integrate Auth0 with Shopify so our clients can log in to our application with their Shopify credentials. I have tried using the Shopify social connection in Auth0 (https://marketplace.auth0.com/integrations/shopify-social-connection), but it only works for a single store.
Does anyone have the same use case? I would like to get some insights into how people address this problem.
Thank you.
I tried using Shopify social connection but it only allows connecting to one store. I'm expecting multiple Shopify customers to log in with their Shopify credential.
